# How to calculate the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{6}{n(n+3)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, telescopic-series

This is a telescoping series whose sum is

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{6}{n(n+3)} = \frac{11}{3}$$

I calculated it as $$\left(\frac{2}{1} - \frac{2}{1+3}\right) - \left(\frac{2}{\infty} - \frac{2}{\infty+3}\right) = 2 - \frac{2}{4} = \frac{3}{2}$$

However, the answer was
$$2\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{3}\right)= \frac{11}{3}$$
How was this calculated? It seems like they just added a few numbers out of the whole series.

Comment: Please edit your question and use correct latex

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: You got the terms to the form $a_n - a_{n+3}$, where $a_n \to 0$. To use the usual telescoping series formula, you really need $a_n - a_{n+1}$, where $a_n \to 0$. The standard trick is to note that$$a_n - a_{n+3} = (a_{n + 2} + a_{n+1} + a_n) - (a_{n+3} + a_{n+2} + a_{n+1})$$where $a_{n+2} + a_{n+1} + a_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution:**

Since $\forall k\in \mathbb{Z}^+$, there holds that

$$
\frac{6}{k(k+3)}=2\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+3}\right),
$$

we can calculate the partial sum

\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{6}{k(k+3)}\\
=~&2\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+3}\right)\\
=~&2\left[\left(1-\frac{1}{4}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{5}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{6}\right)+\cdots+\left(\frac{1}{n-2}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\\
+\left(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+3}\right)\right]\\
=~&2\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}-\frac{1}{n+3}\right).
\end{align}

Hence, the original infinite sum is

\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{6}{k(k+3)}\\
=~&\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\lim} 2\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}-\frac{1}{n+3}\right)\\
=~&2\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\right)\\
=~&\frac{11}{3}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 6):

Whenever we are dealing with infinite series, we should always look at it's partial sums. Consider $N \in \mathbb{N}$, and notice that $$S_{N} = \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{6}{n(n+3)} = 2\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{(n+3)-n}{n(n+3)} = 2\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{N+1}-\frac{1}{N+2}-\frac{1}{N+3}\right).$$ I think you have just missed a few terms while computing the partial sums.

Answer (score 2):

In the language of OP, the correct answer is
$$
2+\frac{2}{1+1}+\frac{2}{1+2}-\left(\frac{2}{\infty}+\frac{2}{\infty+1}+ +\frac{2}{\infty+1}\right)=\frac{11}{3} 
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{3}{n(n+1)} &=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+3}\right) \\
&=\lim _{N \rightarrow \infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n+3}\right) \\
&=\lim _{N \rightarrow \infty}\left[ \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n}-\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{N+3}+\frac{1}{N+2}+\frac{1}{N+1}-1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}\right)\right]\\
&=\lim _{N \rightarrow \infty}\left[ -\frac{1}{N+3}-\frac{1}{N+2}-\frac{1}{N+1}+1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\right]\\&=\frac{11}{6}
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{6}{n(n+1)}=\frac{11}{3}
$$

Answer (score 2):

More generally,
if

$s(k)
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{n(n+k)}
$,
consider the partial sum
$s(k, m)
=\sum_{n=1}^{m} \dfrac1{n(n+k)}
$
where $m > k$.

Then
$s(k)
=\lim_{m \to \infty} s(k, m)
=\dfrac1{k} \sum_{n=1}^{k} \dfrac1{n}
$.

Note that
$s(k)
=\dfrac1{k}H_k
\approx \dfrac{\ln(k)}{k}
$.

Proof.

If $m > k$ then

$\begin{array}\\
s(k, m)
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m} \dfrac1{n(n+k)}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m} \dfrac1{k}\left(\dfrac1{n}-\dfrac1{n+k}\right)\\
&=\dfrac1{k}\sum_{n=1}^{m} \left(\dfrac1{n}-\dfrac1{n+k}\right)\\
&=\dfrac1{k}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{m} \dfrac1{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{m} \dfrac1{n+k}\right)\\
&=\dfrac1{k}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{m} \dfrac1{n}-\sum_{n=k+1}^{k+m} \dfrac1{n}\right)\\
&=\dfrac1{k}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{k} \dfrac1{n}+\sum_{n=k+1}^{m} \dfrac1{n}-\sum_{n=k+1}^{m} \dfrac1{n}-\sum_{n=m+1}^{k+m} \dfrac1{n}\right)\\
&=\dfrac1{k}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{k} \dfrac1{n}-\sum_{n=m+1}^{k+m} \dfrac1{n}\right)\\
d(k, m)
&=s(k,m)-\dfrac1{k} \sum_{n=1}^{k} \dfrac1{n}\\
&=-\dfrac1{k}\sum_{n=m+1}^{k+m} \dfrac1{n}\\
|d(k, m)|
&=\dfrac1{k}\sum_{n=m+1}^{k+m} \dfrac1{n}\\
&\le\dfrac1{k}\sum_{n=m+1}^{k+m} \dfrac1{m+1}\\
&=\dfrac1{k}\sum_{n=m+1}^{k+m} \dfrac1{m+1}\\
&=\dfrac1{k} \dfrac{k}{m+1}\\
&=\dfrac1{m+1}\\
&\to 0\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: +1. Nice generalization.

Comment: Thanks. It seemed to me to be a fairly obvious generalization, and I thought it works better as an answer rather than a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Generalizing Marty Cohen's answer, and assuming $0\le a<b$,
if
$$s(a,b)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{(n+a)(n+b)},
$$
consider the partial sum
$$s(a, b, m)
=\sum_{n=1}^{m} \dfrac1{(n+a)(n+b)}, \text{where $m>b$}
$$

Then
$$s(a,b)
=\lim_{m \to \infty} s(a, b, m)
=\dfrac1{b-a} \sum_{n=a+1}^{b} \dfrac1{n}
$$

Proof.

If $m > b$ then

$$\begin{array}\\
s(a, b, m)
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m} \dfrac1{(n+a)(n+b)}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m} \dfrac1{b-a}\left(\dfrac1{n+a}-\dfrac1{n+b}\right)\\
&=\dfrac1{b-a}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{m} \dfrac1{n+a}-\sum_{n=1}^{m} \dfrac1{n+b}\right)\\
&=\dfrac1{b-a}\left(\sum_{n=a+1}^{a+m} \dfrac1{n}-\sum_{n=b+1}^{b+m} \dfrac1{n}\right)\\
&=\dfrac1{b-a}\left(\sum_{n=a+1}^{b} \dfrac1{n}+\sum_{n=b+1}^{a+m} \dfrac1{n}-\sum_{n=b+1}^{a+m} \dfrac1{n}-\sum_{n=a+m+1}^{b+m} \dfrac1{n}\right)\\
&=\dfrac1{b-a}\left(\sum_{n=a+1}^{b} \dfrac1{n}-\sum_{n=a+m+1}^{b+m} \dfrac1{n}\right)\\
d(a, b, m)
&=s(a,b,m)-\dfrac1{b-a}\sum_{n=a+1}^{b} \dfrac1{n}\\
&=-\dfrac1{b-a}\sum_{n=a+m+1}^{b+m} \dfrac1{n}\\
|d(a,b, m)|
&=\dfrac1{b-a}\sum_{n=a+m+1}^{b+m} \dfrac1{n}\\
&\le\dfrac1{b-a}\sum_{n=a+m+1}^{b+m} \dfrac1{a+m+1}\\
&=\dfrac1{b-a} \cdot\dfrac{b-a}{a+m+1}\\
&=\dfrac1{a+m+1}\\
&{\to 0} \ \ \text{for $m\to +\infty$}\\
\end{array}
$$
Examples:
$$\color{red}{s(a,b)
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{(n+a)(n+b)}
=\dfrac1{b-a} \sum_{n=a+1}^{b} \dfrac1{n}
}\\
s(0,3)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{n(n+3)}=\dfrac13 \sum_{n=1}^{3} \dfrac1{n}=\frac{11}{18}\\
s(1,3)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{(n+1)(n+3)}=\dfrac12 \sum_{n=2}^{3} \dfrac1{n}=\frac{5}{12}\\
$$

Comment: I think you need to add that a and b are positive integers.

Comment: Yes, you are right, $a$ is a nonnegative integer and $b$ is a positive integer.